# Standardize Element API requests

Tags: plugin-elementapi

It occurred to me that in every case I was using Element API, I wanted a standardized way of requesting, as the only thing that needed to change was my transformers.

It seemed helpful to standardize the way the input requests were made, and rely solely on transformers for customization.

Answer (score 2):

Here's what I came up with: https://gist.github.com/timkelty/8de8531df688b6ac08d2da0713b6ff00

This allows you to pass everything through request params, including specifying the transformer class.

Right now it looks for the transformer in the `elementapi` folder: `plugins/elementapi/ElementApi_MyCustomThingTransformer.php`

If a full-fledged CRUD API is baked into 3.0, I'm assuming this will be irrelevant by then.